# Get facebook messeges with Graph API

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get fb messages with Graph API v2.5, but I can't find any api call, which list all of my message in messenger.
I've only found [thread](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/thread), but no idea how to list theese thread-id s.

Is there any solution for this on v2.5 version?

Answer (score 0):

The Chat API has been removed, there is no way to get access to chat messages anymore - except for Page conversations, here´s the link to the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/page/conversations